# How to subclass in Go

Tags: oop, go

In C I can do something like this

```
struct Point {
  int x,y;
}

struct Circle {
  struct Point p;       // must be first!
  int rad;
}

void move(struct Point *p,int dx,int dy) {
    ....
}

struct Circle c = .....;
move( (struct Point*)&c,1,2);
```

Using this approach, I can pass any struct(Circle,Rectangle,etc) that has struct Point as first member. 
How can I do the same in google go?

Comment: That's a pretty messed-up example, why not use: `move(&c.p, 1, 2)` instead of relying on `Circle`'s memory layout ? Also, it does not scale to all shapes, unless you always define a shape from its barycenter ?

Comment: coz Circle internal details are not exported.ie Circle is supposed to be opaque type for the client.

Answer (score 19):

Actually, there's a simpler way to do it, which is more similar to the OP's example:

```
type Point struct {
    x, y int
}

func (p *Point) Move(dx, dy int) {
    p.x += dx
    p.y += dy
}

type Circle struct {
    *Point // embedding Point in Circle
    rad int
}

// Circle now implicitly has the "Move" method
c := &Circle{&Point{0, 0}, 5}
c.Move(7, 3)
```

Also notice that Circle would also fulfill the Mover interface that PeterSO posted.

http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding

Answer (score 8):

> Although Go has types and methods and
>   allows an object-oriented style of
>   programming, there is no type
>   hierarchy. The concept of “interface”
>   in Go provides a different approach
>   that we believe is easy to use and in
>   some ways more general. There are also
>   ways to embed types in other types to
>   provide something analogous—but not
>   identical—to subclassing. [Is Go an
>   object-oriented language?, FAQ.](http://golang.org/doc/go_faq.html#Is_Go_an_object-oriented_language)

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Mover interface {
    Move(x, y int)
}

type Point struct {
    x, y int
}

type Circle struct {
    point Point
    rad   int
}

func (c *Circle) Move(x, y int) {
    c.point.x = x
    c.point.y = y
}

type Square struct {
    diagonal int
    point    Point
}

func (s *Square) Move(x, y int) {
    s.point.x = x
    s.point.y = y
}

func main() {
    var m Mover
    m = &Circle{point: Point{1, 2}}
    m.Move(3, 4)
    fmt.Println(m)
    m = &Square{3, Point{1, 2}}
    m.Move(4, 5)
    fmt.Println(m)
}
```

Comment: PeterSO's answer is idiomatic Go; Go does not permit casting a pointer to another pointer, only casting a pointer to a matching interface -- therefore, he has defined an interface and a number of types that adhered to it.